# Remove a repeating item from a list without getting list index out of range

Tags: python

I am trying to remove all items that have a due date equal to the current day, however, when I use this code because I am removing items from the list it changes the length and then I get the error list index out of range. How do I fix this?

```
 for i in range(len(self.__items)):
     if(self.__items[i]['duedate']==self.__currentDay):
         self.__items.remove(self.__items[i])
         self.__numItems-=1
```

Comment: `self.__items = [i for i in self.__items if i['duedate']!=self.__currentDay]`.  Get rid of `self.__numItems` and just use `len(self.__items)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate backward when you are changing the length of the list during iteration:

```
for i in range(len(self.__items)-1, -1, -1):
    if (self.__items[i]['duedate'] == self.__currentDay):
        self.__items.remove(self.__items[i])
        self.__numItems -= 1
```